# How to scan for decorator tags in javascript build?

Tags: typescript, build, decorator

I wrote a decorator that makes code as obsolete, my question would be, is there a way that I can have a build process that detects this decorator is used in a method, and thus raises some sort of warning?

Like the code below annotated with some decorator:

```
@Obsolete
private deadMethod(){
/// dead code
}

/// throws some warning during build phase
```

Then during NPM build/Webpack build, this decorator usage gets flagged as some warning/error. Is that possible? I was trying to find ways to retrieve what decorators are used in a method programmatically and I couldn't find anything.